# database loaded in webmatrix

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little problem with web matrix and codeigniter, I have included the database and set this in autoload.php :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

I also added information into the config file to connect to my database but I still got error 500.0 at run time.

What else do you think I should add to make it work ?

Comment: your CI version???---> For ci < 1.5:
$autoload['core'] = array('database','db_session'); 

For ci > 1.5
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'db_session');

Comment: you're also breaking out of convention. You should consider only loading the database class when you need it within your model. This will avoid some overhead, keeping your app nice and snappy.